# Visiting Korea as an Indonesian citizen with a US student visa: Do I need a visa for Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I live in Seattle. I am an international grad student in the US.
I carry an Indonesian passport. 
And, I would like to visit Korea for 1 to 2 weeks.

What kind of visa do I need to apply for?
How long does it take to process the visa?
Do I visit an office in Seattle or do I apply for it online?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Korean Tourism Organization, you do unfortunately.
http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/GK/GK_EN_2_1_1.jsp

However there seems to be a South Korean consulate with visa services in Seattle
http://usa-seattle.mofa.go.kr/english/am/usa-seattle/visa/visa/index.jsp

As a side note, I do not think a US student visa grants any special travel exemption as the requirements are generally on your country of citizenship